# Error while installing cucumber on maverick

Tags: cucumber, osx-mavericks

I am getting following error..

```
RROR:  Error installing calabash-cucumber:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--with-gherkin_lexer_ar-dir
--without-gherkin_lexer_ar-dir
--with-gherkin_lexer_ar-include
--without-gherkin_lexer_ar-include=${gherkin_lexer_ar-dir}/include
--with-gherkin_lexer_ar-lib
--without-gherkin_lexer_ar-lib=${gherkin_lexer_ar-dir}/
--with-clib
--without-clib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:509:in `block in try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:530:in `try_link'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:716:in `try_func'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:946:in `block in have_library'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `block in checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:890:in `checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `have_library'
from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2/ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 6):

The telling line in the exception trace is this:

> The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.

From Terminal, run `xcode-select --install` to install the necessary tools and then give installing Cucumber another go.

Comment: Thanks. I had trouble building some gems and this worked for me.